# Highcharts Tooltip Displaying next Elements Data when Hover

Tags: highcharts

How can we show next elements data in tooltip when hovered ..

```
 series: [{ name: 'brightness', data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}, 
              { name: 'temperature',data: [16.4, 194.1, 95.6]}]
```

in the example i want to include when hovered on 29.9,  brightness - 29.9 and temparature - 16.4 both .. shared option in the tooltip gives all the elements but i need immediate next elements data only..

Comment: In case when you have two series, shared option display 29.9 and 16.4.

Comment: thanks for reply Sebastian..the shared option gives me all the series's thats not what i required..i want immediate series name ..